# Is the Euclidean norm unique norm of two-dimensional real vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ is a two-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{R}$ with a norm $\| \cdot  \|: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which, in addition, satisfies these axioms:
$$
\| (x, 0) \| = \| (0, x) \| = | x | \;\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}\label{ax1}
$$
$$
\| (x, x) \| = \sqrt{2}\: | x | \;\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{2}\label{ax2}
$$

Is it possible to prove that the Euclidean norm $\| (x, y) \| := \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the only norm satisfying these additional axioms?
Or find a example of a norm, that is not Euclidean?

A naive attempt can be a function:

$$
\| (x, y) \| = \left\{ \begin{array}{rc1}
(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} & \mbox{for} & x \ne y\\
\sqrt{2}\;|x| & \mbox{for} & x = y \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Which satisfies these axioms, however is discontinuous in case $p \ne 2$.

## Solution

Based on the answer from @Qiaochu Yuan, I found an example of the non-euclidean norm satisfying these additional axioms:

$$
\| (x, y) \| = \left\{ \begin{array}{rc1}
(\sqrt{2}-1)|x|+|y| & \mbox{for} & |x| \leq |y| \\
|x|+(\sqrt{2}-1)|y| & \mbox{for} & |x| \geq |y| 
\end{array}\right.
$$

Another question is whether the enhanced of the requirement from the continuity to the differentiability of the norm will be sufficient for the unique solution in the form of the Euclidean norm.

Comment: The "norm" you guessed is not a norm,  since it does not satisfy the triangle inequality. Take $p=1$ then $||(1,2)||=3$ but $||(1,1)||=\sqrt{2}$ and $||(0,1)||=1$. Then $||(1,2)||=||(1,1)+(0,2)||=3$ is not less then $||(0,1)||+||(1,1)||=1+\sqrt{2}\approx 2.41$

Comment: Yes, the world "norm" is inaccurate designation in this example. The violation of the triangular inequality, proven by you, is precisely due to discontinuity of guessed function (for $p \ne2$). Therefore it is not a norm.

Answer (score 2):

(Norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are necessarily continuous wrt the Euclidean topology.)

A norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is completely specified by specifying its unit ball $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| x \| \le 1 \}$, which must be symmetric (meaning closed under $x \mapsto -x$), convex, and compact (equivalently, closed and bounded (wrt the Euclidean norm)). Conversely, any symmetric convex compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the unit ball of a unique norm (see, for example, [Theorem 1.17 in these notes](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~ttkocz/teaching/1819/asympt-conv-geom-notes.pdf)).

Your conditions specify six points on the unit sphere, namely the points $(\pm 1, 0), (0, \pm 1), \left( \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$. These are six of the eight points of the regular octagon inscribed in the Euclidean unit circle. The solid regular octagon is a symmetric convex compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can take the norm with this unit ball.